# How can I get select option text in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 5.4, I have a form with post method and inside I have a select with some options

```
<select name="selection-list">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

If I use

```
echo $request->input('selection-list');
```

I only got the value of the selected option, but I want the text between selected option tags.

How can I perform this action in Laravel?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't actually a Laravel thing, its more a basic HTML forms thing. The browser only sends the value of the selected option. This is expected behavior.

You either need to have a server side mapping of value to text:

```
$selectionOptions = [1 => 'A', 2 => 'B', 3 => 'C'];
$selected = $selectionOptions[$request->input('selection-list')];
```

Or you can just update the HTML to have the text as the value

```
<select name="selection-list">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Either option should be fine. It really depends on what the rest of the project looks like. If you already have a mapping on the server (this is often used to dynamically generate the HTML elements in the first place ) then the first option may make more sense. Otherwise the second is probably easier.

Comment: The first sentence respond the question. The two options are valid, I will check with our team. Thanks!

Comment: @omixam What do you mean by "The first sentence respond the question"?

Comment: "This isn't actually a Laravel thing, its more a basic HTML forms thing."

Comment: @omixam yes, that was my first sentence. What about it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get text option of the select box just get the value of that select option and now you can get this option form database
just li

```
<select name="brand" style="margin-bottom: 20px !important;" class="custom-select mr-sm-2" >
    @foreach($brands as $id => $name)
    <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

and in your controller just

`$request->brand`